# Shortcut for adding product of two cells along a table row?

Tags: excel

I have a cell which wants to be a total of a table row multiplied by reference cells above the table. For example, `$F$2 * F4 + $G$2 * G4 + $H$2 * H4`. The table extends for about 100 columns which is why I'd like an automatic way to do this (also in case the table ever expands).

To clarify, I know my example works, but I want an automatic way (where I can specify two rows, like `f2:bz2` as the 'reference' row and `f4:bz4` as the other row) to do this. Since the second row is in a table, it would be ideal if the solution allowed for adding another column to the table too.

Comment: What is the problem with your formula? So far it looks ok...

Comment: I know it works, but writing out all cells from `F2 * F4` to `BZ2 * BZ4` is boring and not automatic. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this, preferably a way that takes into account that it's a table row so if the table ever has a column added, it gets automatically added into my formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something that expands automatically with your table, may be this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[@]*OFFSET(Table1[#Headers],-1,0))
```

which assumes that your fixed coefficients are one row above the headers of the table. But it also assumes that you're entering the formula on the same row that you want to process. Unfortunately, if you have the formula to process a different row, you will need to wotk with normal ranges, such as the formula suggested by @pnuts in the comments section. But then it will not scale automatically as your table grows (unless you expand it by *insertion* of columns).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Just to clarify, does the `Table1[@]` section select the row of the table that the formula's cell is in?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$XFD$2)*(F4:XFD4))
```

You will both:

1. avoid REALLY long formulas
2. have a formula that automatically incorporates new columns of data as you add them